# Solr randomized continuous testing framework

Tags: testing, solr, frameworks

Are there any really good testing frameworks for solr ? I heard about [Randomized Continuous Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zD57QKzqdCw) . Does anyone know how to use Randomized Continuous Testing for solr ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is far too broad. There are many test frameworks you can use for Solr (.. almost all of them), and you can use either a live backend or the Embeddable Solr Server for integration testing.

If you watch to the end of the presentation, Dawid gives several examples of how to do randomized testing with Solr and Lucene, including linking to [LUCENE-3492](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3492) which tracks the issue in Lucene and Solr. There is [a Wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TestingSolr) that contains information about how to run the internal Solr tests.